# Styling table rows as full-width cards

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-5

I am trying to style a table such that the rows appear as cards (still with the same row layout, just as a full-width card).

So far I have got this:

```
tbody>tr {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
  border-radius: 0.375rem !important;
}
```

Which produces this result:
[image: resulting table]

This is almost what I am looking for, however I need the cards to be full width so that the data aligns with the headings. Does anyone know how I can do this?

The table markup looks like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xxl-10 col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="p-datatable p-component p-datatable-responsive-scroll" data-scrollselectors=".p-datatable-wrapper" pv_id_11>
                        <div class="p-datatable-header">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-datatable-wrapper">
                            <table role="table" class="p-datatable-table">
                                <thead class="p-datatable-thead" role="rowgroup">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- th's for headings -->
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="p-datatable-tbody" role="rowgroup">
                                    <tr class tabindex="-1" role="row">
                                        <td class role="cell">
                                            "John Smith"
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- other table cells -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- other rows -->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: I've added it to the question. It is a PrimeVue Datatable hence the classes etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend the width of the `<table>` container

HTML :

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
      <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

CSS

```
table {
   width: 100%;
}
tbody>tr {
   display: block;
   padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
   margin: 1.5rem;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
   border-radius: 0.375rem !important;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving padding to the table row you can give it to the table cell to avoid `display: block` issue on the row.

Update: For margin, you can use spacer like below as we can't use margin on the rows without changing the `display`

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
}

tbody>tr {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
    border-radius: 0.375rem !important;
}

tbody>tr td, thead>tr td{
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xxl-10 col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="p-datatable p-component p-datatable-responsive-scroll" data-scrollselectors=".p-datatable-wrapper" pv_id_11>
                        <div class="p-datatable-header">
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-datatable-wrapper">
                            <table role="table" class="p-datatable-table">
                                <thead class="p-datatable-thead" role="rowgroup">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- th's for headings -->
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>2</td>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="p-datatable-tbody" role="rowgroup">
                                    <tr class tabindex="-1" role="row">
                                        <td class role="cell">
                                            "John Smith"
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- other table cells -->
                                        <td>2</td>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <!-- spacer -->
                                    <tr style="border: none !important;">
                                        <td style="padding: 0.5rem;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                    <!-- other rows -->
                                    <tr class tabindex="-1" role="row" style="margin-top: 500px;">
                                        <td class role="cell">
                                            "James Williams"
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- other table cells -->
                                        <td>2</td>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, content is still as appears in my image

Comment: It is currently aligned with the heading. Isn't that what you wanted? Do you want those cards to contain the width until the container's borders?

Comment: yes, I want the cards to appear as the normal rows do, with the data underneath each heading

Comment: Now, I think I understand the issue and solved it. It was because of the `display: block` on the rows. In order to apply padding you can assign it to the cells instead of the rows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but padding is internal to the row, so it is applied *inside* of the border. That means that the row cards still appear touching eachother directly. Do you know of a way to put space between them?

Comment: @user14131782 I am not sure if there is a better way or not for the margin but this is one way you can do it. I just updated my answer. You can copy-paste the spacer where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you might've found a way to work this, but  this is for future visitors.

the problem is caused by `display:blobk;` as mentioned in other answers, i've acually had the same problem using `display:flex;`

luckily both have the same solution, losing the `display:block/flex;`.

### Problem #1:

```
        tbody>tr {
            display: block;
            padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
            margin: 1.5rem;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
            border-radius: 0.375rem !important;
        }
```

[image: display block outcome]
and

```
 tbody>tr {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;

            padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
            margin: 1.5rem;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
            border-r
```

[image: display flex outcome]

#### solution:

losing the display styling.

### problem 2:

removing the display gives an almost viable solution,
but the padding and margin will not take effect now:

```
tbody>tr {
            padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
            margin: 1.5rem;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
            border-radius: 0.375rem !important;
        }
```

[image: without display]

#### final solution:

instead of applying margin to each row, you apply it to the table with `border-spacing:0 1rem;` and most importantly with `border-collapse` as `separate`
final product:

```css
table {
            width: 50%;
            border-collapse: separate !important;
            border-spacing: 0 1rem;
        }

        tbody>tr {
            border-radius: 0.375rem;
            outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175)
            /* we use outline instead of border */
        }

        tbody>tr>td {
            padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xxl-10 col-xl-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="p-datatable p-component p-datatable-responsive-scroll"
                            data-scrollselectors=".p-datatable-wrapper" pv_id_11>
                            <div class="p-datatable-header">
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-datatable-wrapper">
                                <table role="table" class="p-datatable-table">
                                    <thead class="p-datatable-thead" role="rowgroup">
                                        <tr role="row">
                                            <th>
                                                name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                idk
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                idk2
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="p-datatable-tbody" role="rowgroup">
                                        <tr class tabindex="-1" role="row">
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                John Smith
                                            </td>
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                smthin
                                            </td>
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                sm other thing
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- other table cells -->
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class tabindex="-1" role="row">
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                smith john
                                            </td>
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                smthin2
                                            </td>
                                            <td class role="cell">
                                                sm other thing2
                                            </td>
                                            <!-- other table cells -->
                                        </tr>
                                        <!-- other rows -->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### ***important***

if ur hocking your table with datatables use !important on both table styles

```
table {
     width: 100%;
     border-collapse: separate !important;
     border-spacing: 0 1rem !important;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. In the end I switched to using a treelist to display my data, but hopefully this will be useful to someone